# c# How to return a byte array from pdf using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, tiff

All,

i created the following method to take in a tiff byte array with multiple tiff page document

i need to convert this to pdf, then return a pdf byte array

i have 2 problems with this code
**1 - i want to RETURN a byte [].
2 - the pdf generated is repeating the pages.**

```
    public void convertImage(byte[] documentContent)
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\Data\Output.pdf", FileMode.Create)); --for testing purposes



        Bitmap oldImage;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(documentContent))
        {
            oldImage = new Bitmap(ms);
        }


        Size newSize = new Size(1024, 737);


        using (Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(oldImage, newSize))
        {
            int total = oldImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);

            document.Open();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            for (int k = 0; k < total; ++k)
            {
                bmp1.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, k);

                iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmp1, ImageFormat.Bmp);

                var scaleparcent = 72f / img.DpiX * 100;

                img.ScalePercent(scaleparcent);

                img.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(document.PageSize.Height);
                img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(document.PageSize.Width);

                img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

                cb.AddImage(img);

                document.NewPage();

            }
        }

        byte[] bytes = null;

        document.Close();
    }
```

some one help please?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you told it to return a byte array.  You have to tell it that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a basic example:

```
private byte[] CreatePdf()
{
    Document document = new Document();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        document.Close();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

It is similar to a previous answer, but in that answer in isn't made clear that you need to `Close()` the `document` instance *before* you get the bytes from the `MemoryStream`. In your code snippet, you have:

```
byte[] bytes = null;
document.Close();
```

Based on the previous answer, you might change this into:

```
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
document.Close();
```

That would be wrong, because the `bytes` array wouldn't contain the full PDF. Upon `document.Close()`, a lot of essential data is written to the output stream (the info dictionary, the root dictionary, the cross-reference table).

**Update:**

In C#, it is custom to use `using` as indicated in the comments:

```
private byte[] CreatePdf()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

My argument that the `document` needs to be closed to get a complete PDF remains valid: the `document` instance is closed implicitly by the `}` right before `return ms.ToArray()`.

Comment: You should put the `Document` in a `using` inside the block where the `MemoryStream` is instantiated. 
`private byte[] CreatePdf()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks but i dont get it exactly. In my code i am using the documentcontent which contains tiff images in byte array. what in my code do i have to change

Comment: @kayze your comment doesn't make sense: what does TIFF have to do with this question about PDF? What is `documentcontent`? Do not hijack an answered question to post a new question