# Why does breaking out of a foreach loop cause complaint "Cannot access a closed Stream"?

Tags: c#, itext, memorystream, pdf-writer

Based on the suggestion in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123068/how-can-i-assign-the-contents-of-an-itextsharp-text-document-to-either-a-byte-ar), I refactored my method to try to assign data to a MemoryStream outside of the iTextSharp.text.Document "using" (but within the MemoryStream using clause):

```
internal static HttpResponseMessage GeneratePDFOfReportFutures()
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    futureReports = GetAllFutureReports();
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 25, 25, 25, 25)) // the "Rotate" makes it landscape orientation
            {
                using (PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    . . .
                    // "int i" is for testing a quick exit of this long-running loop
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (QueuedReports qr in futureReports)
                    {
                        var tblRow = new PdfPTable(6)
                        {
                            WidthPercentage = 80,
                            SpacingBefore = 4f
                        };
                        float[] tblRowWidths = new float[] { 220f, 180f, 220f, 160f, 160f, 340f };
                        tblRow.SetWidths(tblRowWidths);
                        tblRow.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                        var phraseRptName = new Phrase(qr.ReportName, helvetica9);
                        var cellRptName = GetCellForBorderedTable(phraseRptName, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, BaseColor.WHITE);
                        cellRptName.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                        tblRow.AddCell(cellRptName);

                        . . .
                        tblRow.AddCell(cellRecipients);

                        doc.Add(tblRow);

                        i++;
                        if (i >= 12)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    } // foreach
                } // pdfWriter
            } // doc
            var bytes = ms.ToArray();
            result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", "test")
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        } // memoryStream               
    } // try
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return result;
} // GeneratePDFOfReportFutures
```

With a breakpoint in the "break" line, I step (F10) and the following exception is caught *prior to* reaching the assignment to bytes:

> System.ObjectDisposedException was caught   HResult=-2146232798
>   Message=**Cannot access a closed Stream**.   Source=mscorlib
>   ObjectName=""   StackTrace:
>          at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
>          at System.IO.**MemoryStream**.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.WriteTo(Stream os)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.**PdfWriter**.PdfBody.Write(PdfIndirectObject
>   indirect, Int32 refNumber, Int32  generation)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Add(PdfObject objecta, Int32 refNumber, Int32 generation,  Boolean inObjStm)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Add(PdfObject objecta, PdfIndirectReference refa, Boolean  inObjStm)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PdfBody.Add(PdfObject objecta, PdfIndirectReference refa)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddToBody(PdfObject objecta, PdfIndirectReference refa)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.Type1Font.WriteFont(PdfWriter writer, PdfIndirectReference piref, Object[]  parms)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.FontDetails.WriteFont(PdfWriter writer)
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddSharedObjectsToBody()
>          at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
>          at iTextSharp.text.DocWriter.Dispose()

Since accessing of PdfWriter and/or Doc appeared to be causing the problem, it would seem I need to move the writing code *inside* not only the doc using, but also the pdfWriter using, so I did that, moving the code like so:

```
                . . .
                } // foreach
                var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes)
                };
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", "test")
                };
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            } // pdfWriter
        } // doc
    } // memoryStream               
} // try
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
return result;
```

...but I still get precisely the same exception. However, there is a difference between what I'm seeing now and what's described in the last post in that the exception is not thrown until I F10 on this line:

```
} // pdfWriter
```

If I move the return line above (and still keep it below the catch block) like so:

```
    return result;
} // pdfWriter
```

...the exception is thrown on F10ing on the "return result" line.

Why is this failing, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: It looks like that pdfwriter has a Dispose() that does stuff. This is poor design (since it will also fire when the code in the using block throws an exception). It also makes things hard to debug, as you have found, since things seem to go wrong "for no reason". Having said that, its Dispose() should fire before that of doc or ms.

Comment: Oh, and mark stack traces as code - that tends to make them easier to read.

Comment: Okay, so what can I do about that or how can I work around that? PdfWriter is not my code, it's 3rd party code, as is Doc (iTextSharp).

Comment: It's possible some of the operations on doc you do in that inner `using` are triggering processing that ends up closing `ms`. I'd say: try stepping through the code, keeping an eye on `ms`, in particular its internals (like a closed or disposed flag). That would at least allow you to find at what point the stream gets closed.

Comment: Henk's suggestion prevents the exception, but I'm still not getting the file downloaded for some reason. Very similar code works a treat with Excel files (as shown in the linked post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123068/how-can-i-assign-the-contents-of-an-itextsharp-text-document-to-either-a-byte-ar

Comment: Don't use `using` for `PdfWriter`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095802 Also: you have solved one problem, now you have another problem that has been solved by thousands of developers before you, so the answer is on SO somewhere. In any case: the other problem you mention is visible only in the comments and people how to click "see more comments" to see it. This means that the chance you'll get an answer is close to 0. You did right to post a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126589 but I would suggest you delete this question as it's no longer a question.